# Netbook/laptop with fullsize foldout keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, netbook

Does anyone know of any netbooks or laptops that have fullsize fold out keyboards?  I **really hate** the layout of the keyboards, and considering how small some of the portable folding keyboards are, I'm surprised that I haven't seen netbooks/laptops that have these integrated.

I wouldn't mind if the keys are smaller.  It's just the layout and the lack of standard placements of things like Shift/Ctrl/Home/End keys that I use frequently when programming.

Comment: If you don't like the placement of keys, you can reprogram keys to the keys you want.

Comment: You must be thinking of the ThinkPad 701 "butterfly keyboard"  -- man that'd be sweet.  Too bad the fold-out action might add some bulk/thickness to the unit.

http://bharucha.com/tp701/

Unfortunately, I can't think of any present-day machine that might do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all 17" and above laptops have got full size keyboards with the exceptions of the 2x3 block above the arrow keys and some of the empty spaces.

Alternatively, the best you can probably do is just get an external keyboard and use that!

Answer (score 1):

This is just as much a non-answer as the other one here, but you could try a [bluetooth laser keyboard](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/keyboards-mice/8193/).

Comment: Only works if you're happy to look down at the keys while typing...

Answer (score 1):

How about a USB roll-up keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others use a full size USB keyboard or switch to a 17 inch laptop. I had a folding key board from my Palm, It was better then graffiti but not like a regular keyboard. I know a few companies were working on projected virtual keyboards, but the lack of any tactile feedback may prevent them from being popular.